# How to list cloud storage buckets using wildcard or * in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, spark-streaming

How to list cloud storage buckets using wildcard or * in spark streaming?

I want to list all the buckets from cloud storage which matches gs://bucketname*. I have tried using gsutil which is working but the same is not working from spark read or readstream.

gs://bucket1

### gs://bucket2

---

gs://bucketN

working: gsutil ls gs://bucket*
not working: sc.textFile("gs://bucket*").

Comment: Have you  tried using the python client library as described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets)? You can use a prefix for searching the buckets as mentioned in the docs from the [method](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, my intention is to read the files from more than one bucket into rdd as below: 

sc.textFile("gs://bucket*/my_dir/abcd*.txt")



but, sc.textFile("gs://bucket1/my_dir/abcd*.txt") is working good.

Comment: So you want to list all the files of all your buckets and not only all the buckets?

Comment: yes, correct...

Comment: There is no direct way for you to achieve this. what you can do is iterate through the buckets in order to get the files in each of them, I would go by first getting the list of buckets, save them in an array and then just iterate that array to list the files.